# Does an append-only event store result in an append-only codebase?

Tags: events, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, maintainability

When implementing an application with event sourcing, the persistence engine at work is an event store. That is, an append-only log of events, in past tense, in the order or occurrence. By simply replaying the events through the application, the state at any point in time can be reproduced.

My concern – doesn't this *append-only* event store inevitably lead to an *append-only* codebase? How can you maintain a codebase if removing, or even altering code, might leave the application unable to replay the sequence of events? Can the number of source lines of code ever decrease?

What if a business rule has to be modified, or perhaps worse, what if a nasty bug early in the early days of the application allowed it to enter into a forbidden state? Must the faulty code be kept alive indefinitely? Of course, a lot of these issues can – in theory – be dealt with using event versioning, event schemas, snapshot versioning etc. But hasn't event sourcing become a burden at that point?

Event sourcing is a fairly new technology, at least in production. I suspect that there are few applications that have been running on it for more than a couple of years. What will they look like in 10 years? That's not an unrealistic age for an enterprise application.

Answer (score 1):

> My concern – doesn't this append-only event store inevitably lead to an append-only codebase?

No, it implies an append-only *schema*, which is decoupled from your implementation.

> What if a business rule has to be modified, or perhaps worse, what if a nasty bug early in the early days of the application allowed it to enter into a forbidden state? Must the faulty code be kept alive indefinitely?

Not really - the domain is decoupled from the durable representations.

Yes, there are some common scenarios that you need to incorporate into your design; like the idea that you may need to compensate for errors earlier in the event history.

It's not, fundamentally, different from what you would do if you were only storing current state.  If you have a representation of an aggregate in your database that is in the wrong state, you just update it in place, right? by changing some of the fields to what they are supposed to be.

The idea is the same in event sourcing; you have an event stream that produces a state that you don't want to be in.  You figure out what additional events are necessary to reach the state you should be in, and append them.  Tada.

> Of course, a lot of these issues can – in theory – be dealt with using event versioning, event schemas, snapshot versioning etc. But hasn't event sourcing become a burden at that point?

Not really?  Yes, you need to design flexibility into your schema, so that you can evolve your model aggressively, but at it's core it's not different from storing current state - you *can* still migrate if you have to.

But you also have other levers to play with.

It does, perhaps, require more upfront design capital - you have to think about things like schema lifetimes, and the fact that your book of record accumulates data from multiple revisions of your model.

That *doesn't* mean it's a shoe for all feet.  Designing good message schema is an investment.  If the consumers of that schema (which in this case really means your model, and the subscribers) don't need to evolve independently, then maybe that investment doesn't make sense.